# Improve the join performance on multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables with schemas like below:

```
[User]
id

[Car]
id
user_id  (FK to User)

[House]
id
user_id  (FK to User)
```

Say I have data like:

```
[User]
id
1
2
3
4
5

[Car]
id    user_id
1     1
2     2
3     2
4     2    
5     2
6     2
7     3

[House]
id  user_id
1   1
2   2
3   2
4   3
5   4
```

I want to get a result like below:

```
User ID  car_count  house_count
1        1          1
2        5          2
3        1          1          
4        0          1
5        0          0
```

My current sql runs quite slowly, so I'm asking here to see if there are other ways to enhance the query performance for my case. Thanks!

```
SELECT table1.id, table1.car_count, res2.company_count FROM 
    (SELECT User.id, count(car.id) as car_count FROM User as user 
     LEFT OUTER JOIN Car as car
     ON user.id = car.user_id
     GROUP BY user.id) 
AS table1,
    (SELECT User.id, count(house.id) as house_count FROM User as user
     LEFT OUTER JOIN House as house 
     ON user.id = house.user_id
     GROUP BY user.id) 
AS table2
WHERE table1.id = table2.id
```

Comment: Consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: you should set indexes on the fields you're using in WHERE clauses. Also, it would help to know the source data you want to get the result from

Comment: @lpg In my case I don't have any where condition so far

Comment: @Strawberry Let me update my question, thanks for the feedback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you haven't placed any constraints on the rows returned, it appears that you want counts of all cars and all houses for all users. The following should scan all three tables once each:

```
select user_id, sum(car_count) cars, sum(house_count) houses
from (select id user_id, 0 car_count, 0 house_count from User
      union all
      select user_id, 1 car_count, 0 house_count from Car
      union all
      select user_id, 0 car_count, 1 house_count from House) ilv
group by user_id
```

Comment: Thank you, Mark. It is much faster than my origin query.
It can return a result of 6 million rows within about 5 minis.
(subquery section is over 10 million rows)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT User.id
    ,COUNT(DISTINCT Car.id) AS [car_count]
    ,COUNT(DISTINCT House.id) AS [house_count]
FROM User
LEFT JOIN Car ON User.id = Car.id
LEFT JOIN House ON House.id = User.id
GROUP BY User.id
```

I don't know Mysql can use  Distinct In count but try this Query

Answer (score 0):

Even query performance depend on so many factors like table size, index, column type length so can't say that this query performance will be better...still you are already 2 solution (your's ad Mark), can also check below one..you can try which most suites you.

```
SELECT uid, COUNT(cid) cars, COUNT(hid) house 
FROM
(
SELECT DISTINCT u.id AS uid, cr.id AS cid, hm.id AS hid 
FROM users u 
LEFT JOIN car cr ON u.id=cr.user_id 
LEFT JOIN house hm ON u.id=hm.user_id
) a 
GROUP BY uid
```